# Prime numbers of the form $6k\pm 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I've got a conjecture:-
If $k$ is a natural number, then either $6k+1$ or $6k-1$ is a prime number.
Is this true?

Comment: not true, the gap between prime numbers widens faster than a linear function, this statement assumes that the gap stays the same (or close to it)

Comment: Wrong for $k=20$. (and Vasya's comment indicates that it cannot be rescued by other parameters.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not, say $120+1 = 11 ^2$ and $120-1 = 7\cdot 17$

Answer (score 2):

According to elementary number theory, however, you can represent every prime number in the form $6k\pm1$ so your conjecture I would say is close to true however it does not mean that every number of the form $6k\pm1$ is a prime.
 This, however, holds true only for all primes $\gt3$. That is $2$ and $3$ are not written in this form.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this looks as though it might be true is that $6k\pm 1$ excludes the possible small factors $2$ and $3$, so counterexamples will involve multiples only of $5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, \dots$.

Looking at admissible multiples of $5$ we have $25 (23), 35 (37), 55 (53), 85 (83), 95 (97), 115 (113), 145:143 (11\times 13)$ where numbers in brackets are prime.

John Watson has given an example which works for multiples of $7$.

Conjectures of this kind can look quite compelling if small primes are excluded - even just $2$ and $3$ in this instance, but careful analysis is required before they become truly credible.